# Set-up MySQL Server on Windows 7 64-bit

Tags: mysql, windows, mysql-workbench

I am trying to install MySQL Server on my Windows-7 64-bit machine. I have downloaded MySQL Server Community Edition and MySQL Workbench. I am trying to start a new Server Instance from Workbench. I clicked on `New Server Instance` -> `localhost`, but I am getting the following error

[image]

I have been trying this for the last 6 hours. Any pointer will be great help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are creating a New Server Instance Profile, not a New Server Instance.

If you installed MySQL already, then go to the DOS Prompt and run

```
C:\> net start mysql
```

or

- Click Start
- Click Control Panel
- Click Administrative Tools
- Double Click Services
- Right Click on MySQL and Choose `Start Service`

To verify that MySQL is running on the Windows 7 machine,

- Right Click on Bottom Task Bar and Click `Start Task Manager`
- Click on `Processes` Tab
- Scroll around and Look for the process `mysqld`

Once you have MySQL running on the Windows machine, you can go to to create a Server Instance Profile. The key here is to install MySQL first.