# MySQL Workbench asking for password

Tags: mysql, windows, mysql-workbench

I am trying to set MySQL server on my Windows 7 64 bit machine. I have downloaded MySQL server and MySQLWorkbench.

I have started mysql service by command

```
C:\> net start mysql
```

as suggested [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/21828/10065) and checked that `mysqld.exe` process is running. Now when I do `New Server Instance` in Workbench, it is asking for the password. I never entered or set the password

[image]

**My Question**

Why `New Server Instance` in Workbench is asking for the password?

Comment: Have you tried just pressing OK?

Comment: Yes, and all the three options - Open Database connection, Get Server version, Get server OS turned red with cross in front of them.

Comment: I am glad I could help. However, questions of this nature could be posted on StackOverflow.com or ServerFault.com.

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to give root@localhost a password

Since you just installed mysql, you are running with default settings, this means you have no my.cnf. You will have to create one.

Run the following at a DIS Prompt

```
cd C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5
dir *.ini
```

There, you will see sample `.ini` files. Let's pick my-small.ini

```
net stop mysql
cd C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5
copy my-small.ini my.ini
cd data
del ib*
notepad my.ini
```

Once you open notepad, add this under the [mysqld] header

```
[mysqld]
skip-grant-tables
```

Close notepad and Save my.ini

Next, run these lines

```
net start mysql
mysql (hit enter)
```

You will get a mysql prompt. Now run this:

```
mysql> UPDATE mysql.user SET PASSWORD=PASSWORD('mysecretpassword') WHERE user='root' AND host='localhost';
exit
```

Back at the DOS Prompt, do this:

```
net stop mysql
notepad my.ini
```

Once Notepad is open, delete the line `skip-grant-tables` from my.ini

Close notepad and Save my.ini

```
net start mysql
```

Once mysql is back up, test the password at the DOS prompt

```
mysql -uroot -p (hit enter)
Password: (type mysecretpassword and hit enter)
```

If you get the mysql prompt, CONGRATULATIONS !!! You installed a password for root@localhost

Go back to MySQL Workbench and user `mysecretpassword` as the password

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: I retried it and it work. I cannot thanks you more.