# Reset MySQL root password in LAMPP server on Ubuntu

Tags: mysql, password-recovery

I forgot the password I changed for the root user of MySQL. I'm logged in as root user and when I do
`# /opt/lampp/lampp security`
it gives result as

```
XAMPP: Quick security check...
XAMPP: Your XAMPP pages are secured by a password.
XAMPP: Do you want to change the password anyway? [no] n
XAMPP: MySQL has a root passwort set. Fine! :)
XAMPP: The FTP password for user 'nobody' is still set to 'lampp'.
XAMPP: Do you want to change the password? [yes] n
XAMPP: Done.
```

How do I reset the password. I checked to see, but couldn't find the password in any file (including `my.cnf`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `skip-grant-tables` solution is not a recommended one, for a couple of reasons:

1. It makes the database vulnerable (even with skip-networking)
2. It requires taking your database down *twice*.

A solution which requires taking the database down *just once* is as follows:

1. Create a temporary SQL text file, say `/tmp/init.sql`
2. Within this file, write:

   SET PASSWORD FOR root@localhost = PASSWORD('the_new_password');
3. Add the following to your MySQL config file (on Ubuntu this is on `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`), under the `[mysqld]` section:

   init-file=/tmp/init.sql
4. Restart MySQL once. The init file is read and executed upon startup. The password is reset.
5. Proceed to remove the `init-file=/tmp/init.sql` entry from `my.cnf` (do not forget this). Even as the server is up and running.
6. Remove the `/tmp/init.sql` file.

There are even more solutions! Please refer to a past [blog post](http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/recovering-a-mysql-root-password-the-fourth-solution) of mine. Make sure to check out comment #4 by **strcmp**

Comment: Shutting down once instead of twice ??? That's slick. +1 !!!

Comment: Said comment #4 on linked post shows how to do that with no restart at all.

Comment: I'll bow out my answer. Hat's off to you today !!!

Comment: That was a good lesson. I have favorited this quesiton and bookmarked your blog. Thanks again.

Comment: @Rolando, thanks, and happy to have you visit my blog. But your answer was perfectly valid, I'm sorry you took it off.

Comment: I undeleted it. Still, your answer was so much better and makes sense.

Comment: Under Ubuntu, be sure to place the `init.sql` file under /var/lib/mysql, or AppArmor will deny access to it.

Answer (score 2):

DISCLAIMER : Not an Ubuntu User

I just recently answered a question like this for MySQL under Windows

[MySQL Workbench asking for password](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21835/mysql-workbench-asking-for-password/21841#21841)

I will try to answer this for Ubuntu

STEP 01) Add the following lines under the `[mysqld]` header

```
[mysqld]
skip-grant-tables
skip-networking
```

STEP 02) At OS prompt, restart mysql

STEP 03) At OS prompt, type `mysql` and hit enter

STEP 04) At the `mysql>` prompt, enter this SQL statement (setting `mysecretpassword` as the password for root@localhost)

```
mysql> UPDATE mysql.user SET PASSWORD=PASSWORD('mysecretpassword') WHERE user='root' AND host='localhost';
exit
```

STEP 05) Remove or Comment Out the two lines from STEP 01

```
[mysqld]
#skip-grant-tables
#skip-networking
```

STEP 06) At OS prompt, restart mysql

STEP 07) at the OS prompt, type the following:

```
mysql -uroot -p (hit enter)
Password: (type mysecretpassword and hit enter)
```

If you get the `mysql>` prompt, CONGRATULTIONS !!! You can now connect to mysql as root@locahost with that new password.

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: thank you for the answer. I did not try it. But, I know sure it'll work too ;-)

Comment: I did not have a "password" column, but an "authentication_string" column in the mysql.user table instead. Apart from that, this solution worked great.