# Access denied for user 'root'@'%'

Tags: mysql, authentication, users

I used to access the root user in MySQL just fine. But recently, I am no longer able to.

I am able to login fine :

```
 mysql -u root -p
```

Here is the mysql status after login :

```
mysql> status
--------------
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.28, for debian-linux-gnu (i686) using readline 6.2

Connection id:      37
Current database:   
Current user:       root@localhost
SSL:            Not in use
Current pager:      stdout
Using outfile:      ''
Using delimiter:    ;
Server version:     5.5.28-0ubuntu0.12.04.3 (Ubuntu)
Protocol version:   10
Connection:     Localhost via UNIX socket
Server characterset:    latin1
Db     characterset:    latin1
Client characterset:    utf8
Conn.  characterset:    utf8
UNIX socket:        /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
Uptime:         4 min 16 sec

Threads: 1  Questions: 112  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 191  
Flush tables: 1  Open tables:  6  Queries per second avg: 0.437
--------------
```

But when I want to do any action, such as :

```
mysql> CREATE DATABASE moyennegenerale;
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'root'@'%' to database 'moyennegenerale'
```

I understand `%` is used to signify any host , but my status clearly states localhost. Does somebody have an idea of what might be going on?

Answer (score 21):

I think you have anonymous users

Try running this:

```
SELECT user,host,password FROM mysql.user WHERE user='';
```

This will show what anonymous users exist. Most likely, you will see a line with a blank user, host `%`, and a blank password as shown below:

```
mysql> select user,host,password from mysql.user;
+-----------+-------------+-------------------------------------------+
| user      | host        | password                                  |
+-----------+-------------+-------------------------------------------+
| lwdba     | 127.0.0.1   | *xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx |
| lwdba     | localhost   | *xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx |
| lwdba     | %           | *xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx |
| root      | localhost   | *xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx |
| root      | 127.0.0.1   | *xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx |
| vanilla   | localhost   |                                           |
| mywife    | %           |                                           |
|           | %           |                                           | <<<--- LOOK !!!
| replicant | 10.64.113.% | *xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx |
| kumar     | %           |                                           |
+-----------+-------------+-------------------------------------------+
```

So, how did you login? Run this query:

```
SELECT USER(),CURRENT_USER();
```

### What does this tell you?

- [USER()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_user) reports how you attempted to authenticate in MySQL
- [CURRENT_USER()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_current-user) reports how you were allowed to authenticate in MySQL

The second function `CURRENT_USER()` reveals how which anonymous user was used to log in.

### What privileges did you have when you logged in?

Please run

```
SHOW GRANTS;
```

This will unveil what privileges you had at the time you logged in. The fact that you were blocked from creating a database shows you were not root but some lower-privileged user.

Please clean up your user grants.

- `Feb 17, 2012` : [MySQL : Why are there "test" entries in mysql.db?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13361/mysql-why-are-there-test-entries-in-mysql-db)
- `Feb 17, 2012` : [What is the mysql.db table used for?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13327/what-is-the-mysql-db-table-used-for/13350#13350)
- `Jan 18, 2012` : [MySQL error: Access denied for user 'a'@'localhost' (using password: YES)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10852/mysql-error-access-denied-for-user-alocalhost-using-password-yes/10897#10897)

As for resetting the root password, please do the following:

```
echo "SET PASSWORD FOR root@localhost=PASSWORD('password');" > /var/lib/mysql/rootpwd.sql
service mysql restart
rm -f /var/lib/mysql/rootpwd.sql
```

I learned this [**efficient method from @ShlomiNoach**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/22061/877).

Give it a Try !!!

Answer (score 13):

I know what you did.

Do this:

```
SELECT `User`, `Grant_priv` FROM `mysql`.`user` WHERE `User` = 'root';
```

You will probably notice it returns a 'N' for Grant_priv.  So do this:

```
UPDATE `mysql`.`user` SET `Grant_priv` = 'Y' WHERE `User` = 'root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
SELECT `User`, `Grant_priv` FROM `mysql`.`user`;
```

And walla!  Hope that helps.

Comment: also, for security reasons, you should always delete the root user after creating a new dba.. just make sure they are GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES then at the end WITH GRANT OPTION.. that bit is important.

Answer (score 6):

After you enter as the `root` user check your privileges:

```
 mysql> show grants for 'root'@'localhost';
```

After checking your privileges you can try to give another user all the privileges, or you can try to give the `root` user all privileges again:

```
 mysql> grant all privileges on *.* to 'root'@'localhost';
```

If your `root` user doesn't have privileges you can try to restore them, so:

Stop the `mysqld` server

Restart the server this way `mysqld_safe --skip-grant-table`

Restore `root` privileges with:

```
 mysql> flush privileges;
 mysql> grant all privileges on *.* to 'root'@'localhost' with grant option;
```

Comment: This is what i get after the show grants for 'root'@'localhost' command :  
ERROR 1141 (42000): There is no such grant defined for user 'root' on host 'localhost'

Comment: What's the output of the second command?

Comment: There are a "better" way to do this in Debian, where you don't need to restart the server.  Just as `root` connect as `debian-sys-maint@localhost` and use the password in `/etc/mysql/debian.cnf`.  That user have ALL privileges in MySQL. 
The good thing is you don't need to restart your server.

Answer (score 0):

Your privileges may be be reduced?

Also, you can try to create another account with root privileges.

And delete root user, and re-create with specified privileges.

This may be be helpful:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/resetting-permissions.html

C.5.4.1.2 - LINUX (Make  file with query who create, a new user with full root privileges)

C.5.4.1.1 - Windows (Make file with query who create, a new user with full root privilegles)

Query: (Create root user)

```
  CREATE USER 'new_root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '***';
  GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'new_root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '***' WITH GRANT OPTION MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 0;
```

MySQL Manual Create User:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/adding-users.html

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are running the import query against `information_schema` db, I fell for that for a while because I was using a new MysQL client and didn't realize that the query was trying to create tables in `information_schema` db (since the new db to be created didn't exist when running the query, the connection fell back to the first db in the server).

I tried every single answer here and took me nowhere as root access was used and privileges seemed right.

Answer (score 0):

In my machine, somehow it is solved by simply upgrading Phpmyadmin to the latest version

Answer (score -1):

If you are using AWS RDS, try using '--mc' optional parameter while connecting to specify the session type.

- --mc, --mysql: create a classic MySQL protocol session (default port 3306)
- --mx, --mysqlx: create an X protocol session (default port 33060)

MySQL> \c --mc user:password@hostname:port