# How to add 'root' MySQL user back on MAMP?

Tags: mysql

On PhpMyAdmin, I removed 'root' user by mistake. I was also logged in as 'root'. How can I add the user 'root' back, on MAMP?

Comment: I don't know how MAMP works so not submitting as an answer, but does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6085548/527212) help you?

Answer (score 2):

[MySQL's suggested procedures](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/resetting-permissions.html)

Assuming you went with a generic install of MySQL, my procedure for MAMP is:

**1.** Edit your my.cnf, probably located at: /usr/local/my.cnf, adding the lines:

```
skip-grant-tables
skip-networking
```

**2.** Restart mysqld

```
sudo su -
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin shutdown
nohup /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe &
exit
```

**3.** Change root privs

```
`mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO root@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'password' WITH GRANT OPTION;`
```

**4.** Remove the skip lines from the my.cnf

```
## skip-grant-tables
## skip-networking
```

**5.** Restart mysqld again

```
sudo su -
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin shutdown
nohup /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe &
exit
```

Answer (score 1):

## DISCLAIMER : Not a MacOS user

Here is something quick-and-dirty and very secure.

Step 01) Create a script to create user

If root had a password (such as `mys3cr3t`), run this

```
SQLSTMT="GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* to root@localhost"
SQLSTMT="${SQLSTMT} IDENTIFIED BY 'mys3cr3t' WITH GRANT OPTION;"
echo ${SQLSTMT} > /var/lib/mysql/init.sql
```

If root had no password, run this

```
SQLSTMT="GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* to root@localhost WITH GRANT OPTION;"
echo ${SQLSTMT} > /var/lib/mysql/init.sql
```

Step 02) Restart mysql using the init.sql file

```
service mysql restart --init-file=/var/lib/mysql/init.sql
```

Step 03) Remove /var/lib/mysql/init.sql

```
rm -f /var/lib/mysql/init.sql
```

All Done !!! *No need to use skip-networking or skip-grant-tables*.

In the past, [I used to recommend restarting mysql twice](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/22054/877).

[**@Shlomi Noach's answer**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/22061/877) had a one-restart approach, which I now recommend to others.

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: you also need "WITH GRANT OPTION" when recreating root! ;-)

Comment: GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* to root@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'mys3cr3t' WITH GRANT OPTION