# reset mysql root password on ubuntu

Tags: mysql, password-recovery

In short: my goal is to reset mysql root password on ubuntu.

Background: I set up a ubuntu desktop and installed LAMP stack last week. I then went to do something else, and just got back to carry on today. Either I did not set mysql password, or I have forgotten what I typed in.

So I tried to reset it.

I stopped mysql by

```
sudo stop mysql
```

I tried to start mysql using command line options, but it seems start only takes service name(??)

So I ran:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start --skip-network  --skip-grant-tables
```

Went into mysql, fine. Then

```
mysql> UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('newpasswd') WHERE User='root';
ERROR 1142 (42000): UPDATE command denied to user ''@'localhost' for table 'user'
mysql> show grants for ''@'localhost';
+--------------------------------------+
| Grants for @localhost                |
+--------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO ''@'localhost' |
+--------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

If ''@'localhost' has USAGE on all-schemal.all-tables, I'd think I can just update the password like this... Where did I miss?

I used the instruction in [mysql official website](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html), the last part. I also tried the unix one but with no luck. And I was unsure when it says 'unix', does it mean all *nix system or just unix???

Anyway, any thoughts are welcome! many thx!!!

Answer (score 4):

Here is a more secure way to reset password without `skip-grant-tables`

Suppose you want root to have `myn3wp@ssw0rd` as the password

Step 01 : Create a script to execute when mysqld first start up

Create a file called `/var/lib/mysql/init-file.sql` with these two lines

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* to root@localhost
IDENTIFIED BY 'myn3wp@ssw0rd' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Step 02 : Run these three(3) lines in the OS

```
chown mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql/init-file.sql
service mysql restart --init-file=/var/lib/mysql/init-file.sql
rm -f /var/lib/mysql/init-file.sql
```

Step 03 : THERE IS NO `STEP 03`. YOU ARE DONE !!!

Give it a Try !!!

## CAVEAT

- [I used to recommend two restarts of mysql that required editing `my.cnf`](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/22054/877)
- [I learned a better approach from @ShlomiNoach](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/22061/877)
- This answer improves on it more by not editing `my.cnf` at all

## UPDATE 2013-06-17 07:05 EDT

OK Since mysqld for Ubuntu does not like [**init-file**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_init-file) on the command, you must edit the `my.cnf`. Please do these next two steps

STEP 01) Add these lines to `my.cnf` under the `[mysqld]` group header

```
[mysqld]
init-file=/var/lib/mysql/init-file.sql
```

STEP 02) Allow mysql to read files from /etc/mysql

```
sudo vim /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld
```

Add the line:

```
/etc/mysql/*.sql r,
```

STEP 03) Restart MySQL

This should work for you. Give it a Try !!!

Comment: Thx very much for your reply! I tried your suggestion, but "service mysql start --init-file=/var/lib/mysql/init-file.sql" gives an error, "start: invalid option: --init-file=./init-file.sql". Basically ubuntu does not like any options after start?

Comment: I updated my answer on what to do next...

Comment: I proposed an edit. the [mysqld] section is missing the init-file=, also need to include apparmor section I found here: http://serverfault.com/questions/330034/mysql-init-file-config-option-giving-file-not-found-error

Answer (score 1):

From the error given it seems that you are not logged in at all.

1)Stop the mySql server:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
```

2)Start the mysqld configuration.

```
sudo mysqld --skip-grant-tables &
```

3)Login to MySQL as root.

```
mysql -u root mysql
```

4)Replace YOURNEWPASSWORD with your new password!

```
UPDATE user SET Password=PASSWORD('YOURNEWPASSWORD') WHERE User='root'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES; exit;
```