# How to reinitialise /var/lib/mysql files?

Tags: mysql, linux, debian

Due to a mishap I deleted the entire /var/lib/mysql directory. Since the database did not contain anything important, I do not want to go through the hassle of restoring it from an old backup, but instead create the directory structure from scratch. How do I do it without reinstalling MySQL?

Comment: (Wanted as comment, but I don't have enough reputation)

This works for me too, but it deletes root access. To fix this see: . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41645309/mysql-error-access-denied-for-u    A comment from a user whise answer may get deleted

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You should be able to just [run `mysql_install_db` from the command line](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-install-db.html)

> mysql_install_db initializes the MySQL data directory and creates the system tables that it contains, if they do not exist. It also initializes the system tablespace and related data structures needed to manage InnoDB tables. As of MySQL 5.6.8, mysql_install_db is a Perl script and can be used on any system with Perl installed. Before 5.6.8, it is a shell script and is available only on Unix platforms.

[Please read the MySQL Documentation in full for `mysql_install_db`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-install-db.html), then ...

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!

If it does not work on the first try, do this

```
mkdir /var/lib/mysql
mkdir /var/lib/mysql/mysql
chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql
```

then run [`mysql_install_db`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-install-db.html) again

Comment: It worked on the first try. Thx. The password is another issue.

Comment: See my post http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44645/reset-mysql-root-password-on-ubuntu/44647#44647

Comment: you may also need to `restorecon -r /var/lib/mysql` if SELinux is enabled

Comment: Note: This is now depreciated! See "Cristian Deluxe" answer below for modern 5.7 MySQL

Answer (score 15):

For MySQL 5.7 > just:

```
# Move or remove the original dir
mv /var/lib/mysql /tmp/mysql

# Create a new dir
mkdir /var/lib/mysql

# Change owner to mysql (user and group)
chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql

# Create MySQL initial data
mysqld --initialize
```

Comment: the only answer that's worked for me

Comment: mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.22, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

Comment: Can confirm, this fixed a reinstall issue on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Server.

Answer (score 1):

*(Wanted as comment, but I don't have enough reputation)*

This works for me too, but it deletes root access. To fix this see:
[mysql-error-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41645309/mysql-error-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/190174)